# Dynamically rendering tiles in mapnik

Tags: mapnik

I am working on a mapping project on an embedded system (~1 Ghz, 512MB RAM, 2GB flash storage). It is not feasible to pre-render all of the tiles and setup a tile server. Instead, I was planning to use mapnik to dynamically generate images from a custom sqlite database.

Is this a reasonable plan or will I run into problems?

If so, is there a better design approach to take?

Comment: I agree that it is probably not a viable platform for a dynamic tile generator (such as GeoServer). I would definitely test out the file size of your tiles - depending on the resolution and coverage area you could easily surpass 2GB in storage requirements, even with any compression offered by a database!

Comment: You need to provide more information about the content you have to display. But that seems a very light config for a map server. If you are only displaying vector data covering a small area, you might be fine though.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with these samples:

https://github.com/pocketIlmatto/mapnik_node_tile_server

or

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Howto_real_time_tiles_rendering_with_mapnik_and_mod_python